# Why is my "a href" button not linking to my php file page?

Tags: html

When I click on my `a href` button `<a href="browser.php">Check your browser</a> </br>`
 why isn't the button linking to the `browser.php` page by opening up that page when I click on that specific button from my `index.html` button page?

Here is my folder structure in case I made an error with the file path but I don't think I did.

**File structure**:

[image: File structure image]

Just to confirm, I'm trying to get this button `a href` button `<a href="browser.php">Check your browser</a> </br>`
 on my `index.html` page when clicked to lead me to the `browser.php` page.

**index.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <h1>Mohammed - My Index Page</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <img src=""></img>
    <a href="browser.php">Check your browser</a> </br>
    <a href="">Check your screen resolution</a> </br> 
    <a href="loginData.php">Login</a> </br> 
    <a href="create_user.php">Signup</a> </br> 

</body>
</html>
```

**BROWSER.PHP CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />
    <body class="browser">
    <title>Browser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

function get_browser_name($user_agent)
{
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) return 'Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) return 'Safari';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) return 'Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7')) return 'Internet Explorer';

    return 'Other';
}


echo get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly into one of my websites, and it seems to be working just fine. It's nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Hi, the page code just displays when I click on the button https://imgur.com/a/sju78pV

Comment: @JamesAuthor looks like your opening the files locally. You need to set up a server (such as an apache server) to run your php server side.

Comment: I tried this, however when I click on the button it downloads the PHP code. Apache is running as well. https://imgur.com/a/KdqCXVD

Comment: @JamesAuthor What permissions are set on the PHP file? Try running `chmod 755 browser.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try directly opening the browser.php from your web browser.

Also check downloading an external Apache server like Xampp or Wamp and again running the code.

The code is working fine in my Apache installation and I am using Xampp server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to open php file directly from the browser, you should Apache server to run your php file in local server. For that you have two option Install any one of below:

> 1.Xampp
>
> 2.Wampp

Then you can check the way of running php or html files through local servers.